# Phpmyadmin is not opening when start lampp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, lampp

I started lampp **sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start** then open phpmyadmin on localhost but it gives me error like below

[image]

I tried to change config.inc.php like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = "root";
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = "root";
/* Optional: Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = "phpmyadmin";
```

But still it shows me this error

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem it was because another mysql service was running and in parallel mysql in xampp I was trying to run. So you may check that out if other solutions don't work out.

You can stop that by the following command:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

May help few users.

Comment: that's the problem exactly